# "relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32" issue while using HWAddressSanitizer

Tags: clang, out-of-memory, address-sanitizer, sanitizer

I try to use the `HWAddressSanitizer` option in clang on an `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`, but it results in a `relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against '.data'` error while compiling.

The compiler comes from the `clang-12` package installed by `apt-get`.

The compilation command used:

```
clang++-12 a.cpp -fsanitize=hwaddress
```

The error report:

```
/tmp/a-ea2385.o: in function `main':
a.cpp:(.text+0xbe): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.rodata'
/tmp/a-ea2385.o: in function `__cxx_global_var_init':
a.cpp:(.text.startup+0x7): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.data'
a.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.data'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The program tested:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        printf("HelloWorld\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Some answers online suggest using `-no-pie` option but it doesn't work.

How can I sucessfully compile the program with HWAddressSanitizer enabled?

Comment: Are you sure `clang-12` supports `-fsanitize=hwaddress` on `x86_64` _at all_? Does the same problem happen with `clang-15` ?